# Динамическое получение Expandable ListView. Android

Tags: java, android, listview

Клиент-серверное приложение по воспроизведению радио-каналов.

На главном экране **ExpandableListView**. При запуске приложения запрашиваем от сервера список "Group" 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача в том, чтобы при раскрытии элемента "Группы" нужно получить данные от сервера "Child"

Понимаю что при раскрытии Группы вызывается `getChildView()` вопрос. Что лучше использовать AsyncTask, IntentService или еще какие-либо инструменты.

Прошу поделится мнением или примером. Спасибо!

Comment: лучше использовать проверенные библиотеки для работы с сетью, вроде OkHTTP

Comment: Плюс грузите данные сразу же и для главного view и для childView

Comment: Если бы была возможность грузить сразу и childView и Group View проблем бы не было. 
Задача как раз динамически прогружать ChildView