# Динамическая подгрузка Expandable ListView (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, adapter, retrofit

Есть список стран, он статичен (Россия, Китай, США и.т.д), у каждой страны есть список городов. 
Использую ExpandableListView с кастомным Адаптером: 
Список стран присваиваем как `Group`, а список городов необходимо подгружать с сервера динамически и запихивать в `Child`

Вопрос. как из Adapter сделать запрос на сервер и использовать в `expandableListView` ?

P.s Без Expandable - не вариант. Для запросов использую Retrofit.

Comment: Какой-то абстрактный вопрос. В реализации адаптера можно сделать `AsyncTask` и коннектиться к серверу. Затем в `publishProgress` пихать это в список

Comment: Запрос к серверу должен посылаться когда юзер кликнул по элементу группы. Тоесть вызвался метод `getChild`. Но за время когда AsyncTask отработает метод уже вернет null.

Comment: не понял, что именно вернет `null`? Почему вернет?

Comment: А зачем [два](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532209/Динамическое-получение-expandable-listview-android) почти одинаковых вопроса?

Comment: @pavlofff, закрыл как дубль на этот вопрос. Странно, что система дала это сделать даже при отсутствии плюсов на ответе тут)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Запуск запроса к серверу должен происходить не в методе отрисовки элемента адаптера, а в методе-слушателе нажатия на элемент-группу.
2. Далее, запустив в этом месте задачу скачивания инфы и получив ответ, вам надо добавить полученные данные в список, коий отображается адаптером.
3. После этого уведомить адаптер о изменениях методом `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: В том и проблема. Что запросы нельзя послать в главном потоке. 
Есть метод OnGroupClick , если в нем запустить поток с подключением то пока придет ответ приложение уже выкинет exception.

Можно как-то приостановить главный поток?

Comment: @Алексей, если в момент клика по группе данных нет, то адаптер и не должен пытаться что-то отобразить и, соответственно, падать. А усыплять главный поток не стоит - есть риск получить падение по `ANR` - "приложение не отвечает". В общем, вы, видимо, что-то не то в адаптере написали.

Comment: Ты оказался прав. Спасибо!